# Database Consolidation - Named instance vs default instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have searched SO, but cannot find a question/answer close enough.

We are busy consolidating our database servers, partially due to address performance issues using cross-server (cross-instance - SEE: RPC) queries.  A lot of extra thought is put to trying to manage the "chunk of data over the linked server" vs just letting the compiler help.

During installation, we are faced with the issue of using the default instance (.) vs. using a named instance MSSQL2016.  My experience, thus far, suggest the named instance for two reasons - obscurity for security (to a lesser degree) AND the flexibility for side-by-side (upgrade, test, etc.).  We use Alias' anyway, so pointing them after installation to the "SAME" instance or different, is not going to make any real difference.

We currently have a cluster and plan to move it into a single HyperV VM.  The CPU for the host (64 cores 128 GB Memory) "purrs" at 10%, so we want the compiler to start working for it's meal.

SUMMARY:  Best Practice - Should we install a named instance or use default instance for production.  Most of us are programmers - so more bang for buck is better.

Comment: Is the new VM going to host a cluster or multiple instances per environment (test/dev/etc) or both?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic First Part of question: We want to take away the cluster in totality.  We want a single server (for LIVE) with all our major databases on a single instance.  Most of our systems require getting data from other operational systems constantly.  We use SSRS - generally through a stored procedure fetching data across database.  Datawarehouse in the mix, but more for somewhat historic to historic.  Second Part of Question:  Mostly likely a separate VM per environment - as per recomm AND to curb runaway performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a default instance.  You can always add additional named instances later.  But with VMs it's increasingly rare to need multiple instances per VM.